# Get Entities through common relation

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have three entities - **Company**, **User**, **Accessgroup**. I need to restrict User access to Companies with Accessgroups.

Users and Accessgroups is many to many, Companies and Accessgroups is many to many.

For example, User '*Murphy*' have relation with Accessgroups '*Detroit*' and '*Delta-City*, and Company '*OCP*' have relation with Accessgroup 'Detroit'.

How can I pull Companies that have same Accessgroups with User?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, one should use TypeORM Query Builder.

First of all, get accessgroups Ids that user have relation with.
For example, let's said that user *Murphy* included in accessgroups with `agIds: [1, 2]`.
Then we could get all Companies that user have access with this query:

```
this.companiesRepository.createQueryBuilder('company')
.innerJoin('company.accessgroups', 'accessgroup', 'accessgroup.id IN (:...ids)', {ids: agIds})
.getMany();
```